# How to configure nginx to just add to request one more HTTP header

Tags: nginx

I tried to add HTTP header to request that going to http://myserver.org:19123,

But nginx not even catch this request.

What is wrong in configuration below :

```
server {
    listen       19123;
    server_name  myserver.org;

    access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header  Proxy-Remote-User vasya;
        #proxy_pass   http://myserver.org:19123;
    }       
}
```

How to configure nginx to catch this request and add to him HTTP Header?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you are actually asking about, but have you checked out nginx's `add_header` parameter? http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersModule#add_header

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to do, you will need to add the header before it is sent to the proxy (first config), then check for that header in the second config.  With what you have you are just setting the header twice.

Comment: no, this two cases not related, I just need somehow attach http header to request in second case. Going to remove first case to not confuse people